# SQL Server - How to copy data from dropped table when DROP_TABLE TRIGGER fires after table is dropped?

Tags: sql-server

I do not wish to prevent table drops, but when certain tables are dropped in a database I would like to back up either the entire table or query the rows and select specific rows into another table before the drop.

With a normal trigger on a table, if a row was deleted you could access the 'Deleted' table and access those deleted rows.

The DROP_TABLE trigger fires after the table is dropped.

Is there an equivalent to the Deleted table for a DROP_TABLE trigger?
Is there a different approach I could use?
Or am I going to have to re-code the business logic in the windows service which creates and drops these tables?

(I *REALLY* don't want to write a trigger which rolls-back the drop, accesses and copies-out the data, then re-drops the table without firing the trigger recursively. I like inventiveness, but this is too mucky a solution for me)

I am running this on Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition (64-bit)
and Microsoft SQL Server Developer Edition (64-bit)

Comment: Who is dropping your tables?  Is it done as a matter of course?

Comment: Maybe instead of dropping the tables, you could `sp_rename` them out of the way, and drop them as part of another job (which also backs up the data).

Comment: Steve - it is not a case of 'who' is dropping the tables - they are designed to be dropped. They are temporary, dynamic objects with a short lifecycle used as part of a variable user-defined process.

When we perform our next code release we could choose to put in a process to soft-delete+move tables. However this is part of a commercial platform and we can't just release adhoc code.

I did not want to burden anybody with any of this detail in case it deflected away from the question in hand - about potential trigger-based methods for obtaining a copy of data from tables about to deleted!

Comment: Adding a trigger is releasing adhoc code too - Why is this any different?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done except for perhaps the mucky way you suggest. There's no sort of `BEFORE` or `INSTEAD OF` for DDL triggers, so the table is already gone when you access it on `FOR DROP_TABLE` (I built you a DDL trigger to test that, can post if you like). If you had any ideas that this was possible due to strange wording on the documentation, I'm afraid not - regular contributor here Aaron Bertrand filed this on MSDN connect as an issue - [see here.](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/752210/doc-ddl-trigger-topic-suggests-that-rollbacks-run-before-action)

Comment: Hi Bridge - actually I did successfully try the mucky way in a dev environment - but due to the number of steps involved I did not feel it was an appropriate solution for release (even temporarily) into a live production environment - I just posted in here to see if I was missing something obvious

Comment: @SteveHenderson Not that I can see I'm afraid! I did some google searching over the last 20 mins or so, and can't find anything relevant either. Lets hope someone out there knows something we don't, good luck.

Comment: Also Steve - does your system necessarily need to work on tables? Could your user defined process not work on views instead, so the underlying tables are untouched and the data is not lost when they're dropped?

Comment: Bridge - Thanks for looking. Unfortunately not - again, not wanting to get too deep into the process, the table structure and data are dynamic (from a single column/row to 17GB of long-text and XML) - so it is not like I could just re-define views to bring data in and out of a view (if that is what you mean)

What is happening - if it helps - is that users can create and modify their own relation data structures. When that data is used a copy of the data is taken to avoid contention if the user decides to make changes to their data - hence the temporary and dynamic tables

Comment: Someone may have mentioned this, but if dropping the tables is a matter of course (poor practice imo) - it should mean there is foreknowledge of their drop. Why not put `AFTER INSERT` triggers on these "temporary business objects" so that the data they accumulate is "saved" and the `DROP TABLE` can occur without further event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys, but to directly answer my own questions:

1. For DDL triggers (which fire for DROP TABLE), there is no equivalent to the Deleted table within DELETE/UPDATE triggers
2. There is no equivalent solution without rolling-back the drop, copying-out the data and re-issuing the drop
3. The only appropriate and correct approach is to re-code the business logic in the windows service which creates and drops these tables - to permit a soft-delete/move/rename when required

Answer (score 0):

If it's the recursive firing of the trigger that bothers you, that can be checked for. This will only run for the initial DROP TABLE.

```
alter Trigger ddlt_ProcessDropTable
on all server for drop_table
AS
begin
    if( trigger_nestlevel() = 1 ) -- only run if top level drop table
    begin
        declare @data XML
        set @data = EVENTDATA()
        -- rollback the drop
        rollback;

        -- get table name
        declare @TableName sysname, @SchemaName sysname, @DataBaseName sysname, @Sql nvarchar(1000);
        select 
            @TableName = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)'),
            @SchemaName = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)'),
            @DataBaseName = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)')

        /****
        Do stuff with the dropped table...
        ****/

        -- re-drop the table
        set @sql = 'Drop Table ' + 
            QuoteName(@DataBaseName) + '.' + QuoteName(@SchemaName) + '.' + QuoteName(@TableName)
        exec(@sql)
    end

end
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Jim - I think I could also just prevent recursive firing of triggers by setting the nested triggers server option to 0 by using sp_configure - although I have not investigated this; because as I have said, because of live-platform constraints I was explicitly NOT looking for a process which rolls-back the drop, accesses and copies-out the data, then re-drops the table.